# Collatz sequence longest steps

Tags: haskell

I have to write a program that given n natural number verifies that for all 1 ≤ k ≤ n, the number k satisfy the Collatz Conjecture, and returns the minimum value m, 1 ≤ m ≤ n, that generates the longest sequence of steps from  a1 = m up to 1. For example:

```
*Main> longestSequenceTo 13
9
*Main> longestSequenceTo 30
27
*Main> longestSequenceTo 88
73
*Main> longestSequenceTo 1121
871
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```
longestSequenceTo :: Integer -> Integer 
longestSequenceTo n = longestSequenceToAux n 1

longestSequenceToAux :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
longestSequenceToAux n m | satisfyCollatzAux (m) < satisfyCollatzAux (m+1) = longestSequenceToAux n (m+1) 
                         | satisfyCollatzAux (m) > satisfyCollatzAux (n) = longestSequenceToAux (n-1) m
                         | otherwise = n

satisfyCollatzAux :: Integer -> Integer
satisfyCollatzAux n | n == 1 = 0
                      | mod n 2 == 0 = satisfyCollatzAux (div n 2) + 1
                      | mod n 2 == 1 = satisfyCollatzAux (3*n + 1) + 1
```

This code run the examples above, but it doesn't for all n numbers. It is mandatory to use recursion.

For example 20, the number that has to return is 18, because 20 has 7 steps to get to 1 and 18 has 20 steps to 1. But there is a problem with 19, it has the same steps to 1 like 18.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a number for which this does not work?

Comment: Where do you define `satisfyCollatz` that you use in your `longestSequenceToAux`?  And I think you are off by 1, I think that when n==1, collatz=1, not 0.

Comment: The logic inside `longestSequenceToAux` doesn't entirely make sense to me, although it may rely on some theorem of which I'm not aware. It seems like you're starting with the range `[1, n]` and first increasing the bottom bound until you find the local maximum of collatz sequence length, then doing to same for the top bound. But the sequence length is not monotonic, the local maximum is not the maximum for the range. Have you tried simply `maximum (satisfyCollatzAux [1..n])`?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is not doing what you expect. Consider the first 20 numbers:

```
a   collatz(a)  n   m   1st guard  2nd guard    otherwise
1     1        20   1   TRUE       FALSE
2     2        20   2   TRUE       FALSE
3     8        20   3   FALSE      FALSE        >>> n = 20
4     3             
5     6             
6     9             
7    17             
8     4             
9    20             
10    7             
11   15             
12   10             
13   10             
14   18             
15   18             
16    5             
17   13             
18   21             
19   21             
20    8
```

Your algorithm stops at `n=20, m=3`, returning the value of n in your function, which is 20.

It's evident looking at these numbers that you want to get a=18, which is the smallest number that produces the longest sequence (21).

Using recursion, a function that calculates the maximum value could be something like this:

```
myMax mx [] = mx
myMax mx (x:xs) | mx > x    = myMax mx xs
                | otherwise = myMax x  xs
```

Where the variable `mx` is storing the maximum value found so far. The difference in your case is that you need to save not only the maximum value of the collatz length, but also the number `a` that produced it. So, your storing value `mx` should be a tuple of (a, value). See if you can do the changes.

If you want to call your function like `longestSequenceTo n`, you need to 1) expand your `a` values to something like `[1..n]` 2) apply your `SatisfyCollatzAux` function to each `a` value, 3) find your maximum (a, value) using a recursion function similar to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Always break problems down into smaller ones.

First define a function to calculate how many steps the Collatz formula takes to reach `1` for any given number.

```
collatzSteps :: (Integral a1, Num a2) => a1 -> a2
collatzSteps = collatzSteps' 0
  where
    collatzSteps' c n 
      | n == 1         = c
      | n `mod` 2 == 0 = collatzSteps' (c+1) (n `div` 2)
      | otherwise      = collatzSteps' (c+1) (n * 3 + 1)
```

Next we define a function that will recursively iterate over a range from `1` to `n`. Each iteration if the Collatz steps for `n` are greater than the `maxSteps` argument, we call the function recursively, updating that `curMax`. When `n` is greater than the limit, we return the current `smallestNum`.

```
longestSequenceTo :: Integral a1 => a1 -> a1
longestSequenceTo n = aux (0, 0) 1 n
  where
    aux curMax@(smallestNum, maxSteps) n limit 
      | n > limit        = smallestNum
      | maxSteps < steps = aux (n, steps) (n+1) limit
      | otherwise        = aux curMax (n+1) limit 
          where steps = collatzSteps n
```

```
Prelude> longestSequenceTo 13
9
Prelude> longestSequenceTo 30
27
Prelude> longestSequenceTo 88
73
Prelude> longestSequenceTo 1121
871
```